# MapBox - How the get Points of Building Shape/Edge

Tags: rest, mapbox, endpoints

I would like to get the points of the shape of a building using mapbox. Is it possible?
For example I would like to get the red point of a building like in the image below:

[image: Red points of building]

I'm going to use Swift, but maybe these kind of data can be retrieved using some end-point exposed by mapbox rest API.

Comment: Do you need the geographic coordinates of the buildings edges or just the plain shape ?

Comment: Geographics coordinate. Thx

Comment: Additional: I would like to get geogrpahic coordinate (lat,lon). I don't know what I you mean with "plane shape".

Comment: Okey now i know what you want ! I will take a look tomorrow

Comment: Do you want to get the geometry of the building by its name or coordinates?

Comment: It's the same, I think each building has its own identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not programmatically** you can do the following:
Based on the [overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) you can take use of the [overpass API turbo engine](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). With that engine it's possible to extract all the data from the OpenStreetMap database including geometries of buildings and their coordinates. If you want to query ALL buildings in a specific boundary box just do:

```
 (
  way[building]({{bbox}});
  >;

 );
  out skel;
```

Here goes the [**EXAMPLE**](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jDM) in the engine.

If you want to set search conditions based on buildings, you may want do the following:

```
(
  way[building][key=value]({{bbox}});
  >;

 );
  out skel;
```

Here is an [**EXAMPLE**](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jDP) to get a building in a given bounding box with the name *"Istituto Professionale Servizi Commerciale"*.

**Programmatically** just do a **POST** request with your progamming language of choice. An example URL could like the following, where the coordinates are the bounding box of the request:

```
https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=(way[building][name~%22Istituto%20Professionale%20Servizi%20Commerciale%22](41.89217881581378,12.488332986831665,41.89511780763163,12.492608428001404);%3E;);out;
```

The returned result is as default an **XML**.

If you want to return your result in a **geoJSON** just do:

```
https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(way[building][name~%22Istituto%20Professionale%20Servizi%20Commerciale%22](41.89217881581378,12.488332986831665,41.89511780763163,12.492608428001404);%3E;);out;
```

Accessing the "*elements*" key of each polygon will give you the attributes of your corner edges of the polygon in geographical coordinates (lat, lon).

Comment: What I was looking, grazie.